# The correct way to create given template

Tags: html, css

I recently found template, which was in the quiz and tried to reproduce given template that was on the image. The tricky part about it is that the quiz already closed and i can't submit my answer for reviewing. I'm still curious about correctness of my template, so i want to ask you, HTML guru's, if i reproduced it right.

Thank you in advance!

IMAGE:

[image]

LINK: [Codepan](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/NgyaNM)

HTML:

```html
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
      <meta charset="UTF-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
      <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
      <title>Document</title>
    </head>
    <style>
      * {
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0;
      }
      body, html {
        height: 100%;
      }
      div, header  {
        height: 100%;
        min-height: 50px;
        float: left;
        border: 2px solid black;
        box-sizing: border-box;
      }
      header {
        width: 100%;
        height: 25%;
        text-align: center;
      }
      .wrapper {
        height: 75%;
        width: 100%;
      }
      .wrapper > .first-column, .wrapper > .second-column {
        height: 100%;
        width: 50%;
      }
      .wrapper > .first-column > div {
        width: 100%;
      }
      .wrapper > .first-column > .first-row {
        height: calc(100%/3);
      }
      .wrapper > .first-column > .second-row {
        height: calc(100% * 2/3);
      }
      .wrapper > .first-column > .second-row > div {
        height: 100%;
        width: 50%;
      }
      .wrapper > .first-column > .second-row > .second-column > div{
        height: 50%;
        width: 100%;
      }
      .wrapper > .first-column > .second-row > .second-column > div{
        height: 50%;
        width: 100%;
      }
      .wrapper > .second-column > div {
        height: 100%;
        width: 50%;
      }
      .wrapper > .second-column > .second-column > div{
        width: 100%;
        height: calc(100%/3);
      }
    </style>
    <body>
      <header>
        Test Table
      </header>
      <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="first-column">
    
          <div class="first-row">
    
          </div>
    
          <div class="second-row">
    
            <div class="first-column"></div>
    
            <div class="second-column">
              <div class="first-row"></div>
              <div class="second-row"></div>
            </div>
    
          </div>
    
        </div>
    
        <div class="second-column">
    
          <div class="first-column"></div>
    
          <div class="second-column">
            <div class="first-row"></div>
            <div class="second-row"></div>
            <div class="third-row"></div>
          </div>
    
        </div>
    
      </div>
    
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The beauty ( if you want to call it that ) is that there really is no wrong way ( obviously there is ) but there would be many different ways to mark this up.

**For me**, you've used too many class names, plus I would use more semantic elements such as `<aside>` `<section>` `<main>` `<footer>`.  Which in turn would help eleviate the amount of class names you have.

These would help when looking back at your code and for when applying CSS.

But you've made what you set out to, so nice :-)

p.s. The only thing I would take into consideration, is what would it look like on a mobile device, how would it shrink down? For extra credits ( to yourself ) why not insert some media queries and see how you can make it degrade gracefully without spoiling the experience.